# Image Split Drawer Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, css

I love the functionality of the drop down menu on this site: https://squareup.com/

I see that it's a pretty standard drawer-style drop down, but my question is how they get the image to split like that. After inspecting the code I'm pretty sure they don't use 2 images. Any advice or help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please refine your question providing some effort like a code snippet

Comment: Where is the drop down menu on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image does indeed appear twice. If you run this selector you'll find them.

```
$('.home-page .hero .image, .home-page .banner .image')
```

The second part of the image starts where the first image is cut off by the dropdown, giving the illusion that the image is split into two.

```
media="screen"
@media (min-width: 718px)
.hero-image-split .hero .image {
    background-position: 50% -73px !important;
}
```

For those that couldn't find the split, it occurs when you click on "Business Types" or "Products" on the navbar.